# combine sed commands that switch line order in a file with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have repeating sed commands that switch line 1 and 2, 3 and 4 etc... I would like to combine these commands into one sed command. However when i attempt to combined them it adds duplicate lines and will eliminate some lines.

Edit:

The orininal file out out before sed looks like:

```
Some code....
Some code...
Line-a
Line-b
Line-c
Line-d
Line-e
Line-f
some more...
some more...
```

The code that gives the desired output is:

```
sed -i '2{h;d};3{p;x}' file.txt && sed -i '4{h;d};5{p;x}' file.txt && sed -i '6{h;d};7{p;x}' file.txt
```

The code i would like to use is:

```
sed -i '2{h;d};3{p;x};4{h;d};5{p;x};6{h;d};7{p;x}' file.txt
```

With a desired output from an ordered file of

```
Some code...
Some code...
Line-b
Line-a
Line-d
Line-c
Line-f
Line-e
some more...
some more...
```

Comment: Your example would be much clearer if the lines you don't want swapped weren't identical to each other!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '3,8{N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/}' file
```

For a range of lines, append the following line and using pattern matching, swap them.

If you wanted swap say lines 3-4 and 7-8 use:

```
sed '3ba;7ba;b;:a;N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/' file
```

Or swap lines 3-5 and 6-8, use:

```
sed '3,8{N;N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\3\n\2\n\1/} file
```

Comment: This is exactly  what i was looking for. Would you mind explaining the syntax.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using GNU sed, (**$!**) unless current line is the last line in the file, (**x**) swap contents of pattern space and hold space, (**n**) read a new line into pattern space, (**G**) append the content of hold space to pattern space with a line feed. (**p**) Print the contents of pattern space.

```
$ cat file
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
$
$ sed -n -i '$!{x;n;G};p' file
$
$ cat file
two
one
four
three
six
five
seven
```

---

To make it a hundred percent POSIX compatible you need to give up on inplace editing and break the script into multiple commands:

```
sed -n -e '$!{x;n;G;}' -e 'p' file
```

---

This answers [the first version of OP's question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56157812/1). Since with their latest edits it became undecipherable, I refuse to edit.

Comment: yes im using GNU sed. I have edited the question to reflect more detail. Your answer shows me i need to use the correct switches. However i dont want to rearrange the whole file only particular lines.

Comment: Yes, the question did change a lot. I never saw that first version.

Answer (score 4):

This is a completely inappropriate task for sed. Just use awk, e.g. with GNU awk for "inplace" editing since that seems to be a priority for some reason and using a modified sample input file so it's clear which lines are and are not being swapped:

```
$ cat file
with a some code here
and a some code there
Line-a
Line-b
Line-c
Line-d
Line-e
Line-f
here a code, there a code
everywhere a code, code

$ awk -i inplace 'NR>=3 && NR<=8{if ((++c)%2) p=$0; else print $0 ORS p; next} 1' file

$ cat file
with a some code here
and a some code there
Line-b
Line-a
Line-d
Line-c
Line-f
Line-e
here a code, there a code
everywhere a code, code
```

Other than the GNU-only `-i inplace` syntactic sugar instead of `> tmp && mv tmp file`, the script will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

---

Original response and other examples below:

```
$ awk 'NR%2{p=$0;next} {print $0 ORS p}' file
Some code...
Some code...
Line-b
Line-a
Line-d
Line-c
Line-f
Line-e
```

The above will work using any awk in any shell on any UNIX box.

Only want to swap between lines 4 and 7, say? That's a trivial tweak because **it's the right tool for the job**:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR<=3 || NR>=8{print; next} (++c)%2{p=$0;next} {print $0 ORS p}'
1
2
3
5
4
7
6
8
9
10
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ seq 10 | awk 'NR>=4 && NR<=7{if ((++c)%2) p=$0; else print $0 ORS p; next} 1'
1
2
3
5
4
7
6
8
9
10
```

Want to reverse every 3 lines? Again, trivial because **it's the right tool for the job**:

```
$ seq 9 | awk 'NR%3{p2=p1;p1=$0;next} {print $0 ORS p1 ORS p2}'
3
2
1
6
5
4
9
8
7
```

Hopefully you get the picture...

Answer (score 1):

There is an arguably simpler GNU sed solution<sup>1</sup> to this problem:

```sed
1,2b   # In the range 1,2 ...
9,$b   # ... and also in 9,$, auto print and end this cycle.
3~2 {  # From line 3 and every second line thereafter,
  h    # hold, then
  d    # delete, and end this cycle.
}
G      # On every other line, append hold space and auto print.
```

Testing:

```
# test.sh

cat > FILE <<EOF
Some code....
Some code...
Line-a
Line-b
Line-c
Line-d
Line-e
Line-f
Some more code...
Some more code...
EOF

sed '1,2b; 9,$b; 3~2{h;d}; G' FILE
```

Output:

```
Some code....
Some code...
Line-b
Line-a
Line-d
Line-c
Line-f
Line-e
Some more code...
Some more code...
```

Note that selecting lines by `first~step` e.g. `3~2` is a GNU extension.

This is based on a generic example of swapping lines in Chap. 6 of O'Reilly sed & awk 2nd ed.

---

<sup>1</sup> But I agree with Ed Morton's comments that AWK is a better fit for this problem.

Comment: i wish i didnt have to but i edited the post again. Thats a clever solution with the tilde but i cant use it for "every line there after". Its completely my fault for not being thorough.  I need to be able to select lines between upper and lower blocks of code and re arrange them. The Awk method is ok but re writing the file become weird. sed does on the spot replacement.

Comment: @goosegoose, I have updated based on your edit. If you know you have exactly 10 lines in your file, then you can actually use "every line thereafter".

Comment: I’m still testing and trying to understand why awk is better. Ultimately I wanted send to avoid sending it to a tmp file then overwrite. But it looks like awk can overwrite.

Comment: @goosegoose The truth is, without us understanding your actual use case, none of us can know which tool to use is the right one.

Comment: @goosegoose wrt you `trying to understand why awk is better` - imagine some small change in your requirements. Anything at all. Maybe print "swapping line number x for line number y" to stderr every time you swap them or ignore lines containing "X", whatever. Now update the sed script to do that and update the awk script to do that. THAT will teach you why awk is better for anything other than `s/old/new/` - because an awk script is a structured C-like program that's easy to adapt while sed is a unique collection of arcane runes that's limited in functionality and differs for every application

Comment: @EdMorton OTOH, you could make the same argument against cut. All it can do is cut fields. If ever your requirements change, you’ll have to rewrite in AWK. If what you need is a one liner that swaps every second line in about 10 characters, sed can do that. Without us knowing _why_ the OP wants to do this, it’s impossible to know the best tool. The best tool could in fact be Ruby or Perl. Maybe a library ecosystem is also required.

Comment: @AlexHarvey here's **my opinion**: no-one ever needs a one liner and brevity is not a desirable quality of software, conciseness is. cut should be used for cutting fields, sed should be used for `s/old/new`, grep should be used for `g/re/p`. Beyond that just use awk until if/when you NEED to use something else since awk is the smallest language of all general-purpose text-manipulation tools and so easiest to learn and if necessary can easily be converted to perl, etc. since it's a subset of them. Also awk is the only general purpose text tool that comes as standard on all UNIX systems.

Comment: @EdMorton you ignore the historical reason sed exists in the first place: to edit code. And in that context, brevity matters. Exiting vim via ZZ rather than wq! saves one keystroke that is multiplied many times over a day. 90% of useful sed scripts actually can be run almost without change in vim eg using vim’s g. If you have no intention to even commit your code, maintainability is not applicable.

Comment: No, I'm not ignoring it any more than driving a car would be ignoring the historical reason a bike exists. sed was invented before awk and so had to do a lot of things that it no longer needs to be able to do. The reason to write maintainable code isn't just for maintaining that code it's so that the next time a slightly different problem comes along you don't have to figure out how to solve that problem, you can just use the same solution you figured out last time with a minor tweak. That's the issue with using sed for more than s/old/new/ - a minor requirements change needs a major revision.